# Determinant algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ and $B$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices with $\det(A) = −2$, $\det(B) = 3$, what is $\det(A+B)$?

At first I approached the problem that $\det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$ but this general rule would not hold true, so I do not know how to approach the problem from here.

Comment: not enough information................

Comment: Please provide more info

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
-3  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $\det (A)=-1$ and $\det( B)=\det( C)=3$. However,
$$
\det(A+B)=8
$$
while
$$
\det(A+C)=0
$$
Your problem is not solvable!

Answer (score 0):

The number $\det(A+B) $ is not determined by the determinants of $A$ and $B$. For instance if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}, \ \ 
B=\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $A$ and $B$ are as required, with $\det A+B=0$. While if$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}, \ \ 
B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $\det A+B=8$.